# How to open declarations in Eclipse on Mac?

Tags: eclipse, macos

I'm using the Eclipse installed within the ADT bundle for Mac. When trying to do open declaration for various variables and method names, I get the error: *"The resource is not on the build path of a Java project"*. Open declaration is only working for my class variables, but not for local variables and method names. I primarily want to use open declaration to check the source of methods declared in different class files. What can I do?

Comment: You're sure that's the error message?

Comment: Locals may only work when you're actually compiling from source, but I would expect to be able to navigate to field and methods in any class  as long as it's on the Java Build Path as indicated.